# How to remove all inner div's based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below markup i want to remove all div's with class as "select"

```
<ul class="container">
   <li>10</li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>10<div class="select"></div></li>
   <li>10</li>
   <li>10<div class="select"></div></li>
   <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), especially http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/remove/. You can easily find the solution to such simple questions by looking at the documentation, which is faster than asking a question here. Also I think you'd find your answer by using the [SO search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+remove+elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$.('div.select')
  .remove();
```

And to be more precise (to delete all such divs in this list) you can use

```
$.('ul.container div.select')
  .remove();
```

Comment: not right that he gets the correct answer... I answered before him, first, with exactly the same answer. No offense Paul.

Comment: @j-man86, No problem. I've put you `+`, bec. I saw that you was nearby and correct. You've answered when I was editing my post and was earlier with the second part of my answer than me. Any offenses J.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('ul.container div.select').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.container > li > div.select').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all `.select` elements within `.container` element and remove them :

```
$('.select', '.container').remove();
```